# Binding collection to ComboBox in Listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, collections, combobox

I have a `ListView` whose `DataTemplat`e consists of a `ComboBox` and some `TextBox`es.
The `ComboBox` is bound to a Collection which is mapped to a CollectionViewSource.
The `ListView` can have any number of rows.

The problem is that selecting an item in one `ComboBox` changes them all. I do want them all to be populated with the same contents, but to be able to be set independently.

The Resources section contains the following:

```
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ChildAccounts}" x:Key="ChildGroupedData">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="group"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <!-- Template for each child item in ListView -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                    
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="210"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Account" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomWhite}" FontSize="14" Width="80"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=accFrom}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ChildGroupedData}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountTemplate}" SelectedValuePath="ID" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource RoundedComboBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomExpanderComboGroupItemStyle}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeader}"/>
                </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="Amount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomWhite}" FontSize="14" Width="80"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=amount, StringFormat='#,##0.00'}" Style="{StaticResource RoundedTextBox}" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="4" Content="Comment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{StaticResource CustomWhite}" FontSize="14" Width="80"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Path=comment}" Style="{StaticResource RoundedTextBox}" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- ListView template -->
    <Style x:Key="ChildListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ChildTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CustomBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,50,0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Makes selection invisible when focus lost -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource CustomBackgroundC}"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

The `ListView` is defined as:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lstChildren" Margin="20,30,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" Style="{StaticResource ChildListViewStyle}"/>
```

EDIT:

The following is found in the associated class

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class ItemView
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub

....

Private _ChildAccounts As ObservableCollection(Of AccountEntry)
Public Property ChildAccounts As ObservableCollection(Of AccountEntry)
    Get
        Return _ChildAccounts
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of AccountEntry))
        _ChildAccounts = value
    End Set
End Property

....

Private Sub ItemView_Initialized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized

    Dim dsacmd As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dsa As New DataSet
    Dim dva As DataView
    Dim strSelect As String

    Try
        ' ** Open a connection to the database.        
        cn = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        cn.Open()

        Me.DataContext = Me

        strSelect = "SELECT Accounts.ID, Accounts.deleted, Accounts.accType, Accounts.currency as curr, IIf([Currencies.ID]=1,Accounts.comment,Accounts.comment & "" ("" & Currencies.symbol & "")"") AS comment, Currencies.comment AS currS FROM Currencies INNER JOIN Accounts ON Currencies.ID = Accounts.currency"
        dsacmd = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSelect, cn)
        dsacmd.Fill(dsa, "Accounts")
        dva = New DataView(dsa.Tables("Accounts"))
        dva.RowFilter = "accType=" & cVirtual.ToString & " AND deleted=False"
        dva.Sort = "curr, comment"
        ChildAccounts = New ObservableCollection(Of AccountEntry)(dva.ToTable.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(i) New [AccountEntry](i("ID"), i("currS").TrimEnd(" "), i("comment"))))

....

Private Sub DisplayItem()

    ....

            strSelect = ""
            Dim Relations As Collection(Of Relation) = GetRelations(ID)
            For Each r As Relation In Relations
                strSelect &= "ID=" & r.ID.ToString & " OR "
            Next
            If strSelect <> "" Then strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE " & strSelect.Substring(0, strSelect.Length - 4)
            If strSelect <> "" Then
                dsrcmd = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSelect, cn)
                dsr.Clear()
                dsrcmd.Fill(dsr, "Items")
                lstChildren.DataContext = dsr
            End If
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move your `CollectionViewSource` into the `DataTemplate`. To force all combobox-items to use the same Source Collection I think you can try two things:

**One** - Use Relative Source to pick the `ChildAccounts` from `ListView`'s `DataContext`

```
...
<Grid.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ChildGroupedData"
                        Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                                          Path=DataContext.ChildAccounts}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="group" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
</Grid.Resources>
...
```

**Update:**

Above method can be seen in **[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5e0d2szg2nw5pf6/MvvmLight3.rar)** sample I put together. Note that ChildAccount's is just an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the view-model, this is so that we are not having a new collection per `ListBoxItem` but share em across like what you had asked for in the question.

If your ChildAccounts property is actually like say the "comment" property where you have a ChildAccounts property object per ListBoxItem, just change

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ChildGroupedData"
                        Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                        AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},
                                          Path=DataContext.ChildAccounts}">
```

to

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ChildGroupedData"
                        Source="{Binding ChildAccounts}">
```

and it should work as well. You do however now have a ChildAccounts collection per `ListBoxItem` and aren't sharing their source.

Main thing is to Define the `CollectionViewSource` inside the `DataTemplate`. Download the attached sample and try it for yourself and check the specifics.

**Two** - Have `ChildAccounts` as a static variable

```
...
<Grid.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ChildGroupedData"
                        Source="{x:Static local:ChildAccounts}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="group" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
  </CollectionViewSource>
</Grid.Resources>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried the first and it doesn't work. The ComboBoxes are empty. Can't get the second to compile. It says 'Cannot find the member 'ChildAccounts' on the target type' and 'l:ChildAccounts member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name. I changed it to {x:Static l:ItemView.ChildAccounts} - which then only gets one error - cannot find the member 'ChildAccounts' on the type 'ItemView'. I have declared xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfAccounts" to allow access to the namespace. The class that contains ChildAccounts in code is called ItemView. Thanks. Andy

Comment: @AndyPowell First method works fine for me. Can you please post your view model code for both ChuldAccounts property and Items property. Trim the code if required. Retain the namespace and class structure. Ill post my working solution to Dropbox as well so you can try in a bit. Is the property Items which is bound to ListView an observable collection of ItemView class objects?

Comment: @AndyPowell I've updated my answer after Option 1 with a link to download a sample project that shows Option 1 working. Download it and have a look to see how your VM property declarations are different. Option 2 as I mentioned in the answer is for Static variables. If your property ain't static you cannot use it.

Comment: Thanks. Will look tonight. I don't think I'm using ViewModel (but will certainly learn from your example). ChildAccounts is declared as a Public Property of ObservableCollection(Of Account) in the Class ItemView. Will update question with the code tonight.

Comment: I think I may have cracked it..... `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ChildData" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ChildAccounts}">` works I think!

Comment: Is ItemView your Window, if so you can actually have the binding with AncestorType={x:Type l:ItemView} instead of AncestorType={x:Type Window} making it type-safe

Answer (score 0):

You can add set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" to the combo box.